# Transition to shrink / expand to auto height element

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

how to write a transition in vue to shrink an element to 0px on disappear, and expand it to auto-height when disappear. Much like with opacity 0 - 1;

```
<transition name="shrink">

..

</transition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't animate height but you could do that using `max-height` :

```
.shrink-enter-active,
.shrink-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.shrink-enter,
.shrink-leave-to {
    max-height: 0;
}
```

this is inspired by my sidebar component [here](https://windy-nuxt.netlify.app/admin) and the code is [here](https://github.com/boussadjra/windy-nuxt/blob/main/components/for_layout/DashboardSide.vue#L157)